# Done button of UIPickerView doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to put a done button to my picker view because, when I slide to choose an item the uipickerview automatically select the slided row, so I prefer have a button done:

```
@IBOutlet var tfProjet: UITextField!
var pvProjetData = ["-Choisir-", "Rachat de crédits", "Renégociation de crédits"]
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let pickerView = UIPickerView()

    if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 100)
    } else if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_5 {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 200)
    } else if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6 {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 200)
    } else if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6P {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 250)
    } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 300)
    }

    //        pickerView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    self.pickerView = pickerView


        let pickerToolBar = UIToolbar()
        pickerToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black //you can change the style
        pickerToolBar.translucent = true
        pickerToolBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // or other colours
        pickerToolBar.sizeToFit()

        let spaceButtonPicker = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButtonPicker = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Ok", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelDatePicker:")
        pickerToolBar.setItems([cancelButtonPicker, spaceButtonPicker], animated: false)
        pickerToolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
        tfDateNaissance.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolBar



        tfProjet.inputView = pickerView


        tfProjet.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolBar
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}


func selectRow(row: Int, inComponent component: Int, animated: Bool){

}

func updatePicker(){
    self.pickerView!.reloadAllComponents()
    pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if tfProjet.isFirstResponder(){
        return pvProjetData.count
    }
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if tfProjet.isFirstResponder(){
        return pvProjetData[row]
    }
    return ""
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if tfProjet.isFirstResponder(){
        let itemselected = pvProjetData[row]
        tfProjet.text = itemselected
        self.tfProjet.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

I see the button Ok, but it doesn't work, when I slide the row is automatically  selected.

Comment: you can take one variable of  `integer type `. and inside the `didSelectRow` `delegate` of picker view  change the value of variable to `row`  of Picker view. create toolbar as you already doing and set the action for button . Whatever action you are doing in  `didSelectRow` do it on the button click action.

Comment: You don't have any `target-action` set up for your "OK" button. You need to set up a function to be called when `OK` is pressed so that you can `resignFirstResponder` or `popViewController` or whatever you want it to do when that button is pressed.

Comment: @MatthewLawrenceBailey You talking about this 
  `  func cancelDatePicker(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
        
        if tfProjet.isFirstResponder(){
            tfProjet.resignFirstResponder() }`

Comment: Yeah i just didn't see that function in the code. Did you set a breakpoint and make sure that func is getting called?

Comment: @MatthewLawrenceBailey this action: "cancelDatePicker:" looks working; but my picker view still gone